# How to fix the html code in django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

This is the template error right now.

```
   NoReverseMatch at /
        Reverse for 'product_detail' not found. 'product_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
        Request Method: GET
        Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
        Django Version: 2.2.6
        Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
        Exception Value:    
        Reverse for 'product_detail' not found. 'product_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
        Exception Location: C:\Users\Others\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 673
        Python Executable:  C:\Users\Others\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
        Python Version: 3.8.0
        Python Path:    
        ['C:\\reet\\mysite\\myshopping',
         'C:\\Users\\Others\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
         'C:\\Users\\Others\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
         'C:\\Users\\Others\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
         'C:\\Users\\Others\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
         'C:\\Users\\Others\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
        Server time:    Tue, 29 Oct 2019 07:01:37 +0000

Error during template rendering
In template C:\reet\mysite\myshopping\shop\templates\shop\base.html, error at line 0
```

I think it's the path specified is incorrect,I not sure how to deal with this error.
Reverse for 'product_detail' not found. 'product_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

```
1   
2   {% load static %}
3   <!DOCTYPE html>
4   <html>
5   <head>
6       <meta charset="utf-8" />
7       <title>{% block title %}My shop{% endblock %}</title>
8       <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}"  rel="stylesheet">
9   </head>
10  <body>
```

I'm not sure how to figure this error,please do help,thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the context that is sent while rendering the template, so that we can actually know wether the values are passed to the template or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this line 27

```
<img src=" {% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% state}" />
```

it should be

```
<img src=" {% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{state}{% endif %}" />
```

Comment: Thank you,that fixed that error,but I have another error displaying,could you look into it?

Comment: Share your urls.py file . You need to give name to the view in your path finction